# Replace or remove compass with bourbon

Tags: css, webpack, sass, compass-sass

I recently bought a template that uses sass with compass. I have been reading and mostly every blog says compass is deprecated. I am looking for a ways to replace or remove compass and use bourbon.

I have not been able to compile the sass with compass, everytime I run `npm run dev` it says there is a variable missing.

Is there any easy way to remove all the mixim call from compass and replace them with bourbon or any way to remove compass overall?

What I am doing right now is looking for any call to the mixins, and replacing them with pure sass or css. I feel like this might take a long time. The folder structure is the following:

```
scss
├── style.scss
├── compass
│   ├── css3
│   │   ├── _animation.scss
│   │   ├── _appearance.scss
│   │   ├── _background-clip.scss
│   │   ├── _border-radius.scss
│   │   ├── etc
│   ├── helper
│   │   ├── _header.scss
│   │   ├── _mixin.scss
│   │   ├── _responsive.scss
│   │   ├── etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your `config.rb` file, where your compass settings are stored, see if there are any links to files that you are currently using.

What you want to do next is remove compass completely by uninstalling it via ruby or deleting it manually.

`gem uninstall compass` in the console. Or, find the dir remove it, and then trace all of your used mixins so that you can remove them too (*this is going to be a bit messy*).

Bourbon does not support all of the functionality presented in Compass, but it sure is the most adequate mixin library to date.

Next, learn to use **[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)**. This is the piece of software that will save you a lot of time and hassle.

`npm install bourbon --save` in the console, and that's it. You simply import it in your SCSS after.

Next, learn to use **[Gulp](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-gulp-js/)**, so that you don't lose more time while developing.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, quick question, since i will be removing the mixin calls, i am guessing i will need to replace those with my own scss? let's say the ` @include border-radius(0px);` i will need to replace that with the code i would normally generate? thanks for the reply

Comment: Yes, you can't eat a carrot from the ground when it's not there anymore. Have a look at the docs - http://bourbon.io/docs/ , there is a mixin for border radius, but you must have a look at what is there and what is not, in bourbon 5.0 a lot of the mixins in 4.*.* are deprecated, have a careful look at the documentation and decide if there are any mixins that you have to write for yourself (which will save you a lot of time by the way). The grid, the reusable blocks, the typography - its all there!

Comment: Thanks for the help, made a lot of things clear for me, well i guess it's going to be a long night. Btw is there a reason why so many mixin are being deprecated, most of them are crossed out.

Comment: Yes, there were a lot of threads on GitHub that concern browser prefixes and maintainability, and the people at thoughtbot decided to keep things lean, simple and ready to use. Here is the main thread about your question - https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/702 and while there is nothing stopping you from staying with v 4.*.* , I suggest you wait a bit for the 5.